# FuelPHP Form validation not working with IE (Internet Explorer) browser... Client side validation not working

Tags: internet-explorer, fuelphp

I'm using `FuelPHP 1.0` version... I create form field validation server side...

eg - `$fs->add('test', 'test', array('type'=>'text'), array('required'));`

`FuelPHP` automatically create the client side validation according to server side validation... and run on `Firefox` and `Chrome`  that client side validation working fine but `IE` `client side validation` not working.... is there any problem with `IE` and `FuelPHP`

Thanks

Comment: I found answer for this question... please go to http://fuelphp.com/forums/discussion/11919/form-validation-not-working-with-ie-internet-explore-browser-client-side-validation-not-working#Item_5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fuel just outputs HTML5 validation rules with the form elements. It's up to the browser to support them.

- Google Chrome (16+)
- Mozilla Firefox (8+)
- and Internet Explorer (10+)

You can implement the [h5validate](http://ericleads.com/h5validate/) jQuery library to simulate the behaviour on unsupported browsers.